# Display is turning on and showing DisplayPort icon

Tags: display, external-display, displayport

My Samsung display is constantly turning on and displaying DisplayPort icon regardless of the state of connected PC (shut down, sleep or just turned off display for power saving). If I connect it through HDMI this problem disappears but HDMI2 doesn't support more then 70Hz in 2k for some reason. Any places where I can look for a solution to this problem? I have no idea where to start as searching on the internet didn't give me anything, as well as looking at user's manual.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was an issue with the cable itself. Even though it was working well for some reason it constantly sent the signal to show DisplayPort icon on the screen. Purchasing another cable helped to sort out the issue.